# how to solve get_bloginfo deprecated function issue in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Notice: get_bloginfo was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.2.0! The siteurl option is deprecated for the family of bloginfo() functions. Use the url option instead. in /home/websi057/public_html/wordpress/breathing/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4031

How to solve this error. My Site is closed due to this error.
I have checked whole website there is no get_bloginfo( "siteurl" ) function in it.

Comment: This is telling you where the issue is, functions.php line 4031. You have `bloginfo('siteurl')` when it should be `bloginfo('url')`.

Comment: There is not a such code in functions.php like bloginfo('siteurl')

Comment: Apologies, I misread the error that is coming from wp-includes. If you can not find it, a plugin your using could be calling it. Have you deactivated the plugins one by one and see if the error goes?

Comment: Its done, In 301 Redirects plugin get_bloginfo('siteurl') is used through which it was showing an error. Thank You Sir.